# Why do I have a 403 error when trying to save a website

Tags: web, copy, httrack

I'm trying to download all pdf files from the ratp.fr website.
However, none of the two (Cyotek and WinHTTrack) website mirroring programs that I tried worked. It seems that, no matter which parameter, user agent I choose or if I decide to ignore robots.txt the answer is still the same: NO.
More precisely, with the first soft I get HTTP 403 error, with the second it's an empty copy.

This is related to that particular website: tried on others and it worked perfectly
How am I supposed to process to save the website?

Thanks

I tried

- each user agent
- limit to the number of connections
- ignore robots.txt

Each time, it leads to an empty copy and a 403 error

Comment: This goes through cloudflare.com as the first thing for me.  Are there cookies/local storage that are needed to let the site know that you've gone through Cloudflare?

Comment: I don't know. In my regular sessions on this website, I randomly have cloudflare interrupt so I think not